# Looking for an app to continously record (and overwrite) audio

Tags: iphone-app, audio-recording

i'm looking for an iOS app that will continuously record audio, wiping over older recordings automatically so it doesn't just fill up the iphone storage. So if something interesting happens, you can go in and say "Save out the last 5 minutes" for example, but otherwise it just keeps on recording and wiping over the recording from 3 hours ago, for example.

Does anyone know if an app like this exists?  thanks